# Status Bar breaks the layout in cordova-ios@4.3.1 when FB dialog opens

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, urbanairship.com, cordova-ios

I have cordova project where i use cordova status bar. I recently upgraded to
cordova-ios to 4.3.1 (previous version was 4.2.1). After the upgrade my status bar gets "pushed" up by (for example) fb dialog when it is opened, which breaks status bar layout (only 60% of the status bar is visible) and the bottom menu is also partially visible. This is only happening on cordova-ios, android is fine.
My cordova is 6.5.0 here are the status bar preferences:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#3e5579" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<preference name="CDVStatusBar" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you might try hiding the status bar and showing it again after a short delay. Not necessarily a great solution; but I'm looking for whether or not the app resizes the view when this happens. If it does, you might be able to use it as a workaround until a proper fix is determined.

Comment: It's not resizing. It's working properly, until the fb dialog is shown... after the user close the fb dialog, they get the above screen.